# Read key value pairs from .txt file and use in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Thanks for looking into my concern.

I have a text file with key value pairs. like version.txt
and content is Version=1.0.0.AA

Now I want to read this text file use this version number inside my scripts.

I am handling this in windows using below script:

```
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (..\version.txt) DO (
    IF /I "%%A"=="version" set APP_VERSION=%%B
)
echo Application Version is "%APP_VERSION%"
```

Could you please help me to achieve the same in Shell scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do

```
source version.txt
echo ${Version}
```

For version.txt

```
Version=1.0.0SomeVersion
```

`source [file]` sources the content of [file] into the script

`Version=1.0.0ABC` happens to be a valid variable declaration in bash

(Hint: there are no spaces between the equal sign, the variable name and the value)

(Hint: Variables in bash are case sensitive)

Because of that you can just source your key-value file and use the contents as variables.

If you want to check if the variable is unset or empty you can use

```
if [ -z "$Version" ]; then
    echo "Version is unset or empty!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I have tried this already. I see some strange issue.
../version.txt: line 1: $'\r': command not found

Comment: That's because the line ending of the file you are using is windows. Do a `dos2unix version.txt` to convert your file to linux file endig.

Comment: Thank you so much.
You are right, it has EOL char's.

Comment: Note: `source` is not POSIX so you may have portability issues to other shells. The equivalent `'.'` operator is. Simply `. version.txt` is guaranteed to work.